# Why does Python crash while returning a C string?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Here's my C code, I made a shared lib out of it. When I load the shared lib in Python and execute the Python code below, I crash. Why?

```
extern "C" { 
PyObject* foo2(char* b) 
{
  return Py_BuildValue("s", b);
}

}
```

And here's what I am doing in Python:

```
   from ctypes import *
   d = cdll.LoadLibrary('./foo.so')
   d.foo2.restype = c_char_p
   v  = d.foo2('hello world')
   print pythonapi.PyString_Size(v)
```

If it helps, I am at Python2.6.

Comment: `c_char_p` – doesn't that mean `char *`? you are **not** returning a `char *`…

Comment: Why are you using `ctypes` to open a library that uses the Python API, instead of making that library a Python extension module?

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is that you're lying about the return type:

```
d.foo2.restype = c_char_p
```

The actual return type is `PyObject *`. But `ctypes` is going to see that `c_char_p`, cast the `PyObject *` to a `char *`, and then try to convert that `char *` to a string with `PyString_FromString`, which is going to read who knows what arbitrary bytes until it hits a NUL character.

The way to specify a `PyObject *` is with [`py_object`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.py_object).

Also, you probably want to set the `argtype`s. And this time, it really *is* a `c_char_p`:

```
d = cdll.LoadLibrary('./foo.so')
d.foo2.argtypes = [c_char_p]
d.foo2.restype = py_object
```

But, as interjay points out in a comment, it's a bit silly to be building a C library that uses the Python C API and then calling it via `ctypes`. This is *occasionally* useful, but normally, the solution is to just finish building a C extension module instead of doing 80% of the work for none of the benefit…

Answer (score 4):

You are telling `cdll` that the function returns a `char*` but in actual fact it returns a `PyObject*`. The two need to be in agreement.